# DirectX-based game display always on top. Need solution

Tags: windows-10, directx

You can see the video of the problem below. When I press the Minimize button, the screen disappears, but when you put the other window on top without pressing the Minimize button, the screen will not be covered and it will always float on top. This problem did not occur in Windows 7, but it occurs after upgrading to Windows 10.

[Problem video](https://youtu.be/POH4p8NbWvw)

I would like to know the DirectX initialization code for the function or function argument related to this problem. (As far as I know, this game uses DirectX 9.)

---

**Additional Information**

Based on Castorix's advice, I used the Spy ++ program to test it. Below is the result screen.

[image]

The problematic program consisted of two windows, a parent window and a child window. The parent window style consists of `WS_CAPTION, WS_MINIMIZE, WS_VISIBLE, WS_CPLISIBLINGS, WS_SYSMENU, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_MINIMIZEBOX, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0x00008000`. And the child window style consists of `WS_CHILDWINDOW, WS_VISIBLE, WS_BORDER`.

---

**Additional Information 2**

If you look carefully at the above video, when the game window goes under the notepad window, the game title bar is hidden, but you can see that the game screen is always on top instead of just being covered.

Comment: Have you tested if the window is Top Most with Spy++ ? (**WS_EX_TOPMOST** extended style)

Comment: @Castorix Thanks for the advice. Related content has been added to the post.